# How to run Python coroutine synchronously until first await like in C#?

Tags: python, c#, python-asyncio

I'm working with some asyncio Python code and I encountered a problem with sequencing of coroutines. I have some experience with C#, so I will use it as an example.

In C# I can write:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    async static Task<int> foo(int n, int delay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo start {0}",n);
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo end {0}",n);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task<int> t1 = foo(1,300);
        Task<int> t2 = foo(2,200);
        
        Task.WaitAll(new []{t2,t1});// Reverse on purpose
    }
}
```

Which results in the following, notice the start of coroutines matches the call order, **not the wait order**. This is guaranteed due to how the coroutine functions are partitioned into a generator. I.e. they always run synchronously until the first `await`.

```
Foo start 1
Foo start 2
Foo end 2
Foo end 1
```

But when I do the same thing in Python I get different order.

```
import asyncio
async def foo(n,delay):
    print(f"Foo start {n}")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay/1000)
    print(f"Foo end {n}")
    return 0


async def main():
    t1 = foo(1,300)
    t2 = foo(2,200)
    
    await asyncio.gather(t2,t1) # Reverse on purpose
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

```
Foo start 2
Foo start 1
Foo end 2
Foo end 1
```

I also know why this is - because `foo(1,300)` returns a generator which does not start until the coroutine is awaited/scheduled.

**My question is how to achieve C#-like behaviour in Python, meaning the coroutines start as they are called without interruption until first `await`?**

I've tried

```
t1 = asyncio.create_task(foo(1,300))
t2 = asyncio.create_task(foo(2,200))
```

which fixed the issue but is the scheduling order really guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio.create_task()`, as the name says, creates a `task.Task` instance. The task is scheduled within the constructor of `task.Task` with

```
self._loop.call_soon(self.__step, context=self._context)
```

From the docstring of `BaseEventLoop.call_soon`:

> Arrange for a callback to be called as soon as possible.
> This operates as a FIFO queue: callbacks are called in the
> order in which they are registered.  Each callback will be
> called exactly once.

So as long as you are using an event loop that doesn't override this behaviour I would say you can use `create_task` the way you intend to. As far as I can tell, none of the event loops in `asyncio` do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Okay, depending on implementation of BaseEventLoop is not ideal for me though. But unless someone suggest something better, I will accept this.

Comment: I'm not sure how big the risk is to rely on that behaviour, but if if you need to control execution order independently of the event loop implementation I only see synchronization primitives as a real alternative. Since the event loop is what schedules execution in any case...This could get kind of cluttered but would definitely signal intent.

Comment: @Quimby Another option is to simply _not_ reverse the coroutines passed to `gather()`. Unlike `WaitAll()`, `gather()` has two purposes: submitting the coroutines to the event loop (which in C# happens automatically by invoking the async function), and waiting for them to all finish. When submitting the coroutines, `gather()` will respect the order in which you provided the coroutines.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks but I cannot rely on gather's order, the real code is more complicated and there is actually no gather soon. I want the order given by calls, not by some loop schedule.

Comment: @Quimby Understood. Asyncio will always respect the order given by calls. A bigger question is why you critically depend on the order in which the taks start executing - while not wrong per se, for me that would be a "design smell". Starting separate tasks conceptually parallelizes the operations. If you need some things started in series, maybe you should code them using different abstractions than tasks (e.g. a queue).

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword *So as long as you are using an event loop that doesn't override this behaviour...* - An event loop can't change behavior of `call_soon` because it's explicitly documented. In theory there could be an event loop whose `create_task()` doesn't use `call_soon()`, but I find it extremely unlikely. Asyncio carefully maintains FIFO semantics, and even fairness (e.g. when [acquiring a `Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock.acquire)), so an event loop that did otherwise while exposing the asyncio API would be incompatible with asyncio programs.

Comment: @user4815162342 Short version is writing I'm async API which uses `StreamWriter.write(); await drain()` deep underneath and I need the writes to be sequenced properly, but if the wrapper itself is async, it does not even start. So `api.write(X); api.write(Y)` calls might result in `YX` if they are actually scheduled in wrong order. So keepin the `write` part synchronous until `await drain()` would really help. I solved it by making `api.write` synchronous and returning a Task that does the second, asynchronous part, but its tedious.

Comment: @Quimby I'd probably use an async queue with a single consumer that does the actual writing. But I'm not sure I fully understand the data flow, especially how the remainder of the work is spawned and how it reports its result back, so I could be off.

Comment: @user4815162342 I agree with everything you said. One thing I'm doubtful about or maybe I didn't get right is about `gather`. The docstring says that scheduling in order of arguments is not guaranteed. @Quimby Regardless of the mechanics of asyncio, since this goes a bit against the design of `Task`s, as user4815162342 pointed out, some sort of synchronization or design change would be best, if not only to signal intent to the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
t1 = asyncio.create_task(foo(1,300))
await asyncio.sleep(0.0)
t2 = asyncio.create_task(foo(2,200))
await asyncio.sleep(0.0)
```

This should always work, since it yields to the event loop after each task creation.  Each task should get started and run to the first await, before the next task is created.  I say "should" because I haven't actually done this in practice myself.  But I would strongly expect it work under all situations.

If you've got a lot of tasks, you can clean up the code with a little function like this:

```
async def start_sequential(*coros):
    for c in coros:
        asyncio.create_task(c)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0)

c1 = foo(1, 300)
c2 = foo(2, 200)
await start_sequential(c1, c2)
```