# How do I collect task garbages in Python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Sorry for the bad English, but I'll try my best.

Consider the following code:

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    async def printA():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('a')
    # create a stream
    stream=...
    async for message in stream:
        pass
asyncio.run(main())
```

Yes, `printA` is not yet used.

Now I want to invoke `printA` when I see some types of messages from the stream.

If I can accept that the stream waits `printA` is done to continue, I can write something like this:

```
async for message in stream:
    if message=='printA':
        await printA()
```

But I can't, so I must write at least:

```
async def main():
    async def printA():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('a')
    # create a stream
    stream=...
    taskSet=set()
    async for message in stream:
        if message=='printA':
            taskSet.add(asyncio.create_task(printA()))
    await asyncio.gather(*taskSet)
```

But if the stream is long enough, `taskSet` would become really big, even if many `printA`(s) are in fact already done.

So I would want them to be removed as soon as they are done.

I don't know how to write this from now on.

Can I remove that task within `printA`? The execution of `printA()` won't be earlier than  `create_task` is invoked, but would it be later than `create_task` returns? Documentation does not seem to guarantee that. Although I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70453413/4950244) says that it is guaranteed by the current implementation.

I can't simply discard the task reference, right? As the doc of `create_task` says:

> Important: Save a reference to the result of this function, to avoid a task disappearing mid execution.

Comment: How big is "really big"? How many tasks are you expecting here?

Comment: Roughly 1 task per minute; in fact it is not "really big", even after a day. But what I want to express here is that I would prefer handle these garbages as well as possible, so I don't need to worry about memory comsuming. If there is a way to handle them, and I know that way, I would handle it regardless it is big or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer directly in the bug report concerning the same problem of "fire and forget" tasks that led to the documentation update *"Important: Save a reference ..."*

https://bugs.python.org/issue44665

I'll copy the recipe for an automatic task removal:

```
running_tasks = set()
# [...]
task = asyncio.create_task(some_background_function())
running_tasks.add(task)
task.add_done_callback(lambda t: running_tasks.remove(t))
```